# How to start a docker container on Ubuntu 19.10 boot?

Tags: docker, ubuntu

How to configure my system to start automatically a docker container on boot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using a local docker container to access database. Always that i restart my system, i need start manually the container with the command `docker start container_name`.

To resolve it, i added the script at Startup Applications.

I followed the bellow steps:

1. Open the Startup Applications with command `gnome-sessions-properties`;
2. Add the command `docker start container_name`.

Done. Always on boot the container will be started.